# Elastic doesn't find the last word in the sentence with the dot in the end

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I use the Elastic with the following settings:

```
ES = {
"mappings": {
    ES_DOC_TYPE: {
        "properties": {
            "message": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "liza_analyzer",
                "include_in_all": False
            }
        }
    }
},
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 4,
    "analysis": {
        "tokenizer": {
            "liza_tokenizer": {
                "type": "pattern",
                "pattern": r"(\. )|[\s,\[\]\(\)\"\!\'\?\`\*\;\:\/<>«»\#]+",
                "flags": "UNICODE_CASE"
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "liza_analyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "liza_tokenizer",
                "filter": ["lowercase"]
            }
        },
    }
}
}
```

When I try to find a word 'hello' in a sentence 'hello world', the Elastic finds it.

When I try to find a word 'hello' in a sentence 'hello. world', the Elastic finds it.

When I try to find a word 'hello' in a sentence 'hello', the Elastic finds it too.

But when I try to find the word 'hello' in a sentence 'hello.' (with the dot in the end), the Elastic doesn't find it.

At the same time the tokens for the two last sentences looks like

```
{
"tokens": [{
    "token": "hello",
    "start_offset": 0,
    "end_offset": 5,
    "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position": 0
}]
}
```

(they are identical)

The question is: why does it happens? How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the exact query you are using?

Comment: `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/liza_index/.percolator/UNIQ_ID4' -d '{"query" : {"match" : {"regexp" : {"message" : "hello"}}}}'` and


`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/liza_index/liza_type/_percolate' -d '{"doc" : {"message" : "hello."}}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is wrong. It should be:

```
"pattern": "(\.\s*)|[\s,\[\]\(\)\"\!\'\?\`\*\;\:\/<>«»\#]+"
```